# How to pause multiple threads in one place and then make one thread do some things? C# (Zennoposter)

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, autoresetevent

I am very newbie with threads and similar things. I know how to use lock-constructions, but no other things. But now the time has come.

I have a program with multiple threads on Zennoposter. I use C# for writing code there. Everything works ok but now i have a problem. I need to execute a piece of code in some places in program by one thread (i have to run an app and initialize project.Tables). I have tried two ways:

1. I paused all threads except the last one before the piece of code and the last thread executed the code. But it did'nt worked for me. I made a list of threads, checked their Status and if the Status was not Suspended i suspended it. But instead of leave the last thread working i just blocked all threads...
2. I used static AutoResetEvent (`static AutoResetEvent waitHandler = new AutoResetEvent(true);`). Then before the place in code with "one thread execution" i had to pause all threads i used `waitHandler.WaitOne();` to make every thread waiting. After this code i used `waitHandler.Set();` to allow other threads to take `waitHandler`. But it made the same thing as lock-constructions:(

The problem is that if a thread comes to place where it has to be stopped and any of other threads still executing code before, it has to wait the any other threads and not excecute the "one thread execution" code.
So, if anybody knows how to solve the problem, please help me. I'm stuck with it for a week.

Answer (score 0):

you need make lock 
sample:

```c#
lock(SyncObject) {

//here your code only for 1 thread, others threads waite

}
```